# Scope issue with ui-router and directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I know similar issues have been raised before and I've worked through lot of them, but as a beginner I still won't get my code to work. I have a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/u9CxCz18wUJpVGUyxOpz?p=preview). My final goal is to have a "listener" for keyboard shortcuts for a template I might want to use across different pages. Upon "enter" it should process the input, but it doesn't. It works fine with clicking the button.

My body looks easy:

```
<body ng-controller="BoxController as box" ng-keyup="box.checkKey($event)">
  <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>
```

My app.js

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('boxApp', ['ui.router']);

  app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

      $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
          url: '/',
          views: {
            'content': {
              template: '<my-box></my-box>',
              controller: 'BoxController as box'
            }
          }
        })
    }
  ]); 

  app.controller('BoxController', function($scope) {
    $scope.userEntry = {txt: 'ye'};

    this.checkInput = function() {
      if ($scope.userEntry.txt == "yeah") { alert("Bingo!"); } 
      else alert("Uh oh: " + $scope.userEntry.txt);
    };

    this.checkKey = function(keyEvent) {
      if (keyEvent.which == 13) { this.checkInput(); }
    };
  });

  app.directive('myBox', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="userEntry.txt"><button ng-click="box.checkInput()"> Check </button>',
    };
  });

})();
```

I'm sure I have some scope accessing issue but I can't figure it out myself. Also: I suspect it would make sense to put the checkKey to a kind of main controller and not include the BoxController to all pages on body. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the preferred behaviour? After typing you want to press enter to submit the form and perform the check - or do you really want to listen to a keypress event, even if the form is not in focus? Second case: use ng-submit on the form.

Comment: Was this issue resolved? The plunker is working as described for me.

Comment: Thanks @JesseBuitenhuis a lot! Yes, I intend to listen to it even if it's not in focus. I tried with form first, but the reason I removed it was: if input is focused and I hit enter, both the form and the listener will fire the event and my function get's called twice. Your plunker is a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do all of this in the directive to keep seperation of concerns.

```
app.directive('myBox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="userEntry.txt"><button ng-click="checkInput()"> Check </button>',
    controller: function($scope, $document){

      $scope.userEntry = {
        txt: ''
      };

      $document.bind('keydown keypress', function(event){
        if(event.which === 13) {
         $scope.checkInput(); 
        }
      });

      $scope.checkInput = function() {
        if ($scope.userEntry.txt == "yeah") {
          alert("Bingo!");
        } else alert("Uh oh: " + $scope.userEntry.txt);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gaNbeECuiOQleJujegVW?p=preview